# When to write tests for improved design during refactoring in TDD

Tags: refactoring, tdd

I am planning to start using TDD. I have read on how RED-GREEN-Refactor cycle works. I am fine with writing Test before code and make it from Red to Green. Though I have basic question on re-factoring: For example: while doing the re-factoring, while I am improving my design, suppose I see a good case for introducing factory pattern and I added this in the code. And my tests may go to RED which I tried to fix to use this new improvement. 
But where I am going to write tests for this new Factory Class which I added during re-factoring? Or it should be like now 
I write tests for Factory class first -> RED
Add Factory class - make the test GREEN
Re-factor this Factory class
Fix other tests in RED

Am I doing thinking something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a refactoring or a design improvement requires to change the external behavior of the code under test or to add new behavior, then it's not appropriate for the refactor phase of the TDD cycle.

A new cycle can be started by writing a test for the factory. When the factory is finished, the factory can be introduced in the code under test in a different TDD cycle.

Answer (score 3):

If you strictly follow the classical Red-Green-Refactor loop you should never have production code that isn't covered by tests. Your unit tests should only verify the behavior from your system under test through its public API and stay away from implementation details.

The goal of the "get to green" phase is to get to green as fast as possible. Any dirty hacks you make are excusable as long as you get to green in this step.

During the refactor phase you can (and should) clean up your code. If this means introducing a new class to tease out independent behavior that does not really belong in the initial class, by all means go for it. These changes are all "safe" since you covered the original code with unit tests. As a refactoring is not supposed to change the behavior of your code, the bar should stay green.

Should you write new unit tests for this newly extracted class? Not really, as it's currently part of the system under test and is covered by your original unit tests.

Note: there are other styles of unit testing that favor testing each class in heavy isolation, so dependening on your TDD style your mileage may vary.

To come back to your example: you are introducing a factory class. Where are you using this factory? Is that code covered by tests (again, if you strictly follow the red-green-refactor loop it should)? If that's the case, you shouldn't have to write new unit tests for the factory, as it is being tested indirectly and can be seen as an "implementation detail".

Comment: thanks, let me know if I got it correctly: once you re-factor code to introduce a factory, **consumer** of this factory has to be updated and consumer tests should be fix for using this new factory. I got till here. But then you mentioned _ you shouldn't have to write new unit tests for the factory, as it is being tested indirectly and can be seen as an "implementation detail"_  Does this mean we can ignore the tests for  code which is solely for improving the quality of code and design and not related to functional and non functional requirements?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your question with a small code example? What exactly do you mean by a factory? Factory method or Abstract Factory? If you say the tests go "red" do you mean they suddenly start failing or a test that doesn't even compile because of breaking changes?